# How to change parameters of widget itself after onComplete function

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I need to find solution on how to change parameters of widget after onComplete function.

```
child: CircularCountDownTimer(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
          duration: 3,
          fillColor: Colors.amber,
          ringColor: Colors.green,
          controller: _controller,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white54,
          strokeWidth: 10.0,
          strokeCap: StrokeCap.round,
          isTimerTextShown: true,
          isReverse: false,
          onComplete: () {},
          textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 50.0, color: Colors.black),
        ),
```

Comment: which parametes you want to change ??

Comment: for example fillColor of CircularCountDownTimer() widget

Comment: simply rebuild `CircularCountDownTimer` with new value of `fillColor` (for example by calling setState`)

Comment: where is onComplete() ??

Comment: it is from package circular countdown timer

Comment: call onComplete() in child

Comment: `onComplete: () => setState(() => _fillColor = Colors.red),`

Comment: /// This Callback will execute when the Countdown Ends.
  final VoidCallback onComplete;

Comment: _fillColor is undefined, how I can initialize it?

Comment: make a field in `State` class: `Color _fillColor = Colors.green;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a variable for the property. For example the color you want to change.

```
  MaterialColor fillcolor = Colors.amber;
```

Then change it inside onComplete method

```
    child: CircularCountDownTimer(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
          duration: 3,
          fillColor: fillcolor,
          ringColor: Colors.green,
          controller: _controller,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white54,
          strokeWidth: 10.0,
          strokeCap: StrokeCap.round,
          isTimerTextShown: true,
          isReverse: false,
          onComplete: () {
            setState(() {
            fillcolor = Colors.purple
            });
          },
          textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 50.0, color: Colors.black),
        ),
```

Comment: Excuse me, how I can change duration? I create an int variable but it is not working

Comment: _controller.restart(duration: 6);
you have to restart it.

Comment: I've one more question, sorry, how can I update the duration more than 2 times?

Comment: @JackSpicy where are you putting _controller.restart ? 
If you will put inside oncomplete setstate, it will call multiple times.

Comment: I'm putting it in oncomplete setstate, but it is not calling multiple times, it skips the first restart method `onComplete: () {
            setState(() {
              _fillColor = Colors.purple;
              _controller.restart(duration: 20); // skips this one
              _controller.restart(duration: 5); // this one works
            });
          },`

Comment: Suppose First time CircularCountDownTimer started with duration 10. which you might declared in the state of your widget. Secondly oncomplete is getting call where duration is  20. Now what will happen is whenever setstate is getting call the timer continuously will till 20 duration.

Comment: Yes, first my widget started with duration 10, after it skips my `_controller.restart(duration: 20)` and only runs `_controller.restart(duration: 5)` What I can do?

Comment: do you want to change the duration on some button click?

Comment: I want to change the duration after my initial duration changing. For example, I've timer, it passes 10 seconds, after it I restart my duration. And after that I need to restart the duration one more time

Comment: By using a flag you can alternatively call the restart function.   if(!flag){
                _duration = 20;
                _controller.restart(duration: _duration);
                flag = true;
              }else{
                _duration = 5;
                _controller.restart(duration: _duration);
                flag = false;
              }

Comment: define flag to false initially .